# HTML Email signature does not move down

Tags: html, css, adobe-illustrator

I have created the following HTML email signature using Adobe Illustrator and rendered HTML out of it. Now when I'm importing this in mail app it does not move down on new lines entered it stays there and my words get overlapped by it.
[image: Words overlapped]

Here is the code of HTML signature:

```
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<div style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; width:280px; height:104px;">
    <div style="background-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/d9o4u9f9zjr3agu/dino_01.png?dl=0); position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; width:280px; height:1px;" title="">
    </div>
    <div style="background-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/o44ty8kq5u4jcfm/dino_02.png?dl=0); position:absolute; left:0px; top:1px; width:112px; height:103px;" title="">
    </div>
    <div style="background-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/m8yjqdnvzt8jqzc/dino_03.png?dl=0); position:absolute; left:112px; top:1px; width:168px; height:42px;" title="">
    </div>
    <div style="background-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/hmq89agn8l0p54h/dino_04.png?dl=0); position:absolute; left:112px; top:43px; width:39px; height:60px;" title="">
    </div>
    <a href="db@itfs.ly"><div style="background-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/mr69z622cd3zr1g/dino_05.png?dl=0); position:absolute; left:151px; top:43px; width:128px; height:14px;" title="">
    </div></a>
    <div style="background-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/jw9d0cydnvujunp/dino_06.png?dl=0); position:absolute; left:279px; top:43px; width:1px; height:61px;" title="">
    </div>
    <a href="tel:021-722-3332 "><div style="background-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/vl4lysbqrfxkf2b/dino_07.png?dl=0); position:absolute; left:151px; top:57px; width:128px; height:12px;" title="">
    </div></a>
    <a href="dl.itfs.ly"><div style="background-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/wlgzyuo7x4rheki/dino_08.png?dl=0); position:absolute; left:151px; top:69px; width:127px; height:35px;" title="">
    </div></a>
    <div style="background-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/3w02m6h0cue91un/dino_09.png?dl=0); position:absolute; left:278px; top:69px; width:1px; height:35px;" title="">
    </div>
    <div style="background-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/65eeqjtnt5sl14v/dino_10.png?dl=0); position:absolute; left:112px; top:103px; width:39px; height:1px;" title="">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Please let me know if there's any CSS rule I'm missing here?

Comment: probably because you have it absolutely positioned: `position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px;`. So it will always be top:0 left: 0

Comment: Most everything in this is absolutely positioned, so it won't display correctly. I 100% recommend just exporting the entire thing as a single image and using that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not just that the outer div was positioned absolutely, but also the inner divs are positioned absolutely. That means the outer div needs `position:relative` in order to have the inner divs position relative to it, rather than the mail body. I also don't think you need the body tag - I removed it, but if that makes things look odd you can add it back in.

```
<div style="position:relative; width:280px; height:104px;">
    <div style="background-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/d9o4u9f9zjr3agu/dino_01.png?dl=0); position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; width:280px; height:1px;" title="">
    </div>
    <div style="background-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/o44ty8kq5u4jcfm/dino_02.png?dl=0); position:absolute; left:0px; top:1px; width:112px; height:103px;" title="">
    </div>
    <div style="background-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/m8yjqdnvzt8jqzc/dino_03.png?dl=0); position:absolute; left:112px; top:1px; width:168px; height:42px;" title="">
    </div>
    <div style="background-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/hmq89agn8l0p54h/dino_04.png?dl=0); position:absolute; left:112px; top:43px; width:39px; height:60px;" title="">
    </div>
    <a href="db@itfs.ly"><div style="background-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/mr69z622cd3zr1g/dino_05.png?dl=0); position:absolute; left:151px; top:43px; width:128px; height:14px;" title="">
    </div></a>
    <div style="background-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/jw9d0cydnvujunp/dino_06.png?dl=0); position:absolute; left:279px; top:43px; width:1px; height:61px;" title="">
    </div>
    <a href="tel:021-722-3332 "><div style="background-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/vl4lysbqrfxkf2b/dino_07.png?dl=0); position:absolute; left:151px; top:57px; width:128px; height:12px;" title="">
    </div></a>
    <a href="dl.itfs.ly"><div style="background-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/wlgzyuo7x4rheki/dino_08.png?dl=0); position:absolute; left:151px; top:69px; width:127px; height:35px;" title="">
    </div></a>
    <div style="background-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/3w02m6h0cue91un/dino_09.png?dl=0); position:absolute; left:278px; top:69px; width:1px; height:35px;" title="">
    </div>
    <div style="background-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/65eeqjtnt5sl14v/dino_10.png?dl=0); position:absolute; left:112px; top:103px; width:39px; height:1px;" title="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make the parent div `relative` instead of `absolute`.

```html
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
Test text

<!-- parent div -->
<div style="position:relative; left:0px; top:0px; width:280px; height:104px;">
    <div style="background-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/d9o4u9f9zjr3agu/dino_01.png?dl=0); position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; width:280px; height:1px;" title="">
    </div>
    <div style="background-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/o44ty8kq5u4jcfm/dino_02.png?dl=0); position:absolute; left:0px; top:1px; width:112px; height:103px;" title="">
    </div>
    <div style="background-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/m8yjqdnvzt8jqzc/dino_03.png?dl=0); position:absolute; left:112px; top:1px; width:168px; height:42px;" title="">
    </div>
    <div style="background-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/hmq89agn8l0p54h/dino_04.png?dl=0); position:absolute; left:112px; top:43px; width:39px; height:60px;" title="">
    </div>
    <a href="db@itfs.ly"><div style="background-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/mr69z622cd3zr1g/dino_05.png?dl=0); position:absolute; left:151px; top:43px; width:128px; height:14px;" title="">
    </div></a>
    <div style="background-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/jw9d0cydnvujunp/dino_06.png?dl=0); position:absolute; left:279px; top:43px; width:1px; height:61px;" title="">
    </div>
    <a href="tel:021-722-3332 "><div style="background-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/vl4lysbqrfxkf2b/dino_07.png?dl=0); position:absolute; left:151px; top:57px; width:128px; height:12px;" title="">
    </div></a>
    <a href="dl.itfs.ly"><div style="background-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/wlgzyuo7x4rheki/dino_08.png?dl=0); position:absolute; left:151px; top:69px; width:127px; height:35px;" title="">
    </div></a>
    <div style="background-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/3w02m6h0cue91un/dino_09.png?dl=0); position:absolute; left:278px; top:69px; width:1px; height:35px;" title="">
    </div>
    <div style="background-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/65eeqjtnt5sl14v/dino_10.png?dl=0); position:absolute; left:112px; top:103px; width:39px; height:1px;" title="">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're setting an `absolute` position instead of `relative` to your `<div>`. Replacing `absolute` with `relative` should do the trick.

On the other hand, you can always export it as a PNG file and attach it to your emails.

Answer (score 1):

Upated first position:absolute to position:relative. Tested and it worked.

```
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<div style="position:relative; left:0px; top:0px; width:280px; height:104px;">
    <div style="background-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/d9o4u9f9zjr3agu/dino_01.png?dl=0); position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; width:280px; height:1px;" title="">
    </div>
    <div style="background-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/o44ty8kq5u4jcfm/dino_02.png?dl=0); position:absolute; left:0px; top:1px; width:112px; height:103px;" title="">
    </div>
    <div style="background-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/m8yjqdnvzt8jqzc/dino_03.png?dl=0); position:absolute; left:112px; top:1px; width:168px; height:42px;" title="">
    </div>
    <div style="background-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/hmq89agn8l0p54h/dino_04.png?dl=0); position:absolute; left:112px; top:43px; width:39px; height:60px;" title="">
    </div>
    <a href="db@itfs.ly"><div style="background-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/mr69z622cd3zr1g/dino_05.png?dl=0); position:absolute; left:151px; top:43px; width:128px; height:14px;" title="">
    </div></a>
    <div style="background-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/jw9d0cydnvujunp/dino_06.png?dl=0); position:absolute; left:279px; top:43px; width:1px; height:61px;" title="">
    </div>
    <a href="tel:021-722-3332 "><div style="background-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/vl4lysbqrfxkf2b/dino_07.png?dl=0); position:absolute; left:151px; top:57px; width:128px; height:12px;" title="">
    </div></a>
    <a href="dl.itfs.ly"><div style="background-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/wlgzyuo7x4rheki/dino_08.png?dl=0); position:absolute; left:151px; top:69px; width:127px; height:35px;" title="">
    </div></a>
    <div style="background-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/3w02m6h0cue91un/dino_09.png?dl=0); position:absolute; left:278px; top:69px; width:1px; height:35px;" title="">
    </div>
    <div style="background-image:url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/65eeqjtnt5sl14v/dino_10.png?dl=0); position:absolute; left:112px; top:103px; width:39px; height:1px;" title="">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```